# How to see when information is lost using API and Glide for images

Tags: java, android, api, stream, android-glide

I'm setting up a NewYorkTimes like news application (using their APIs) for school. I have 3 tabs for each categorie (Top Stories, Most Popular, Arts)
Each tab is a fragment relied to MainActivity and we can switch between fragments using a ViewPager.
Each Fragment contains a RecyclerView. (for article List)
I'm using Retrofit and Glide.
Here is my github repo if you want :https://github.com/matteovaccari/MyNews
I've successfuly implemented Article API but i've been meeting trouble using Glide here's my problem:
Not all images are display (almost 8 images / 10 are display)
and in MostPopular Tab, it's 0/10 images

I think my problem is from my method SetImage:

```
 public void setArticleImage(Result article, RequestManager glide) {
    //If article url isn't null
    if (article.getMultimedia() != null) {
        if (article.getMultimedia().size() > 0) {
            // get image string
            String urlMultimedia = article.getMultimedia().get(0).getUrl();
            // clean the URL
            if (urlMultimedia.startsWith("images")) {
                urlMultimedia = "https://www.nytimes.com/" + urlMultimedia;
            }
            glide.load(urlMultimedia).apply(new RequestOptions().fallback(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)).into(imageView);
        } else {
            // default image
            getImageDefault(glide);
        }
    } else {

        if (article.getMedia() == null) {
            //image default
            getImageDefault(glide);
        } else {
            // get Url
            String mUrlMedia = article.getMedia().get(0).getMediaMetadata().get(0).getUrl();
            // glide the string
            glide.load(mUrlMedia).apply(new RequestOptions().fallback(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)).into(imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

This method is called in my updateUI method (with setTitle, setSection, etc)

I don't understand how some images can be loaded and some don't...
Same for MostPopular tab who don't load anything

Comment: Please don't use the glide tag for questions about the Android image loading library. Use [android-glide] instead. See [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561) and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your **API response**. Some of your images are not loading because your condition `if (article.getMultimedia() != null)` is failing in some cases. In those cases, `multimedia` doesn't exist at all in the API response and hence it doesn't have  any `imageUrl` and hence your **default placeholder image** is loading.

```
public void setArticleImage(Result article, RequestManager glide) {
    //This condition is FAILING for you because article doesn't have multimedia object inside it.
    if (article.getMultimedia() != null) {
        if (article.getMultimedia().size() > 0) {
            // get image string
            String urlMultimedia = article.getMultimedia().get(0).getUrl();
            // clean the URL
            if (urlMultimedia.startsWith("images")) {
                urlMultimedia = "https://www.nytimes.com/" + urlMultimedia;
            }
            glide.load(urlMultimedia).apply(new RequestOptions().fallback(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)).into(imageView);
        } else {
            // default image
            getImageDefault(glide);
        }
    } else {

        if (article.getMedia() == null) {
            //image default
            getImageDefault(glide);
        } else {
            // get Url
            String mUrlMedia = article.getMedia().get(0).getMediaMetadata().get(0).getUrl();
            // glide the string
            glide.load(mUrlMedia).apply(new RequestOptions().fallback(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)).into(imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

You should ask the developer to fix the API response.